# Слайдер работает по разному

Tags: html, css, slider

Использую один и тот же слайдер просто разный текст и картинки(картинки все одного размера). Но в одном примере, как видно, работает и переключает, во втором нет. ЧТо не так? Код прилагается. Уверен, что какой-то пустяк, но я не пойму

```css
 .tur-okno  {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 1100px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        background: #fff;
      } 
  .zatemnenie  {
        background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: none;
      }
       .okno  {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 620px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        background: #fff;
      }
  
      .zatemnenie:target {
    display: block;
    z-index:100;
    }
   .close {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 960px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  }
  .close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  }
  .close:before, .close:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 33px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #333;
  }
      .close:hover {background: #e6e6ff;}
   .close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
 
 /*************************/
 .slider1{
 width: 640px; 
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 320px;
 margin: 100px auto;
 box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 margin-top:-20px;
 margin-left:-1px;
}

.slider1>img{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0; top: 0;
 width:640px;
 height:auto;

}

.slider1 input[name='slide_switch'] {
 display: none;
}

.slider1 label {
 margin: 18px 0 0 18px;
 border: 3px solid #999;
 float: left;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 opacity: 0.6;
}

.slider1 label img{
 display: block;
}

.slider1 input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label {
 border-color: #666;
 opacity: 1;
}
.slider1 input[name='slide_switch'] ~ img {
 opacity: 0;
 transform: scale(1.1);
}

.slider1 input[name='slide_switch']:checked+label+img {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: scale(1);
```

```html
<div id="tur1" class="zatemnenie">
   <div id="okno" class="tur-okno">
    <a href="#"><div class="close"></div></a>
    
    <div class="slider1">
     <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id1"/>
     <label for="id1">
      <img src="img/history1.jpg" width="100"/>
     </label>
     <img src="img/history1.jpg"/>
     
     <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id2" checked="checked"/>
     <label for="id2">
      <img src="img/history2.jpg" width="100"/>
     </label>
     <img src="img/history2.jpg"/>
     
     <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id3"/>
     <label for="id3">
      <img src="img/history3.jpg" width="100"/>
     </label>
     <img src="img/history3.jpg"/>
     
     <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id4"/>
     <label for="id4">
      <img src="img/history4.jpg" width="100"/>
     </label>
     <img src="img/history4.jpg"/>
     
     <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id5"/>
     <label for="id5">
      <img src="img/history5.jpg" width="100"/>
     </label>
     <img src="img/history5.jpg"/>
    </div>
    
    </div>

        </div>
    <a href="#tur1">Подробнее</a>
   <div id="tur2" class="zatemnenie">
   <div id="okno" class="tur-okno">
    <a href="#"><div class="close"></div></a>
   
    <div class="slider1">
     <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id1"/>
     <label for="id1">
      <img src="img/klasdom1.jpg" width="100"/>
     </label>
     <img src="img/klasdom1.jpg"/>
     
     <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id2" checked="checked"/>
     <label for="id2">
      <img src="img/klasdom2.jpg" width="100"/>
     </label>
     <img src="img/klasdom2.jpg"/>
     
     <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id3"/>
     <label for="id3">
      <img src="img/klasdom3.jpg" width="100"/>
     </label>
     <img src="img/klasdom3.jpg"/>
     
     <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id4"/>
     <label for="id4">
      <img src="img/klasdom4.jpg" width="100"/>
     </label>
     <img src="img/klasdom4.jpg"/>
     
     <input type="radio" name="slide_switch" id="id5"/>
     <label for="id5">
      <img src="img/klasdom5.jpg" width="100"/>
     </label>
     <img src="img/klasdom5.jpg"/>
    </div>
    
   </div>
  </div> 
    <a href="#tur2">Подробнее</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, не то, чтобы совсем пустяк - у Вас дублируются id, поэтому работает только первый слайдер. Дублирование id на одной странице недопустимо - это грубейшая ошибка.

Comment: И правда. Это один из моих первых опытов. Увы, таких шишек много набивать придется, т.к самоучка и делаю на коленке)